# RestTemplate request to get JWT token gives unauthorized response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to generate JWT token from auth0. When I send the request from Postman I get the token in response but when I am trying to send the same request using `RestTemplate` I get 401 response. Please advise how to achieve this.

I successfully receive token in Postman.
[image]

Below is the code I am using to send the same request from my controller.

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(){
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("client_id", "xoy6LAdnT1wNyo1SijmhZLACrwAgdfyv");
    map.add("client_secret","o6FWAhS3crc0Vu9ueTpKDBCWWdUelrQAkbIGdsocyqiwfgwS6x6XeyZ5iLQYo1X3");
    map.add("audience","https://contacts-api.com");
    map.add("grant_type","client_credentials");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "https://dev-giudnqk2.us.auth0.com/oauth/token",  HttpMethod.POST, request , String.class);
    return response.getBody().toString();
```

which generates the below error.

```
path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:106) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.shivam.learn.scope.ScopeController.login(ScopeController.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Seems like the id credentials have expired.
Can u generate new id and secret and try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiValueMap` is for submitting parameters (form or query that can have multiple values). You should use `Map` instead.

If you listen to your MultiValueMap based request body with Fiddler it contains the following. Each field contains an array of values.

```
{
   "client_id":[
      "xoy6LAdnT1wNyo1SijmhZLACrwAgdfyv"
   ],
   "client_secret":[
      "o6FWAhS3crc0Vu9ueTpKDBCWWdUelrQAkbIGdsocyqiwfgwS6x6XeyZ5iLQYo1X3"
   ],
   "audience":[
      "https://contacts-api.com"
   ],
   "grant_type":[
      "client_credentials"
   ]
}
```

As you show in the Postman POST payload the JSON should be as follows:

```
{
   "client_id":"xoy6LAdnT1wNyo1SijmhZLACrwAgdfyv",
   "client_secret":"o6FWAhS3crc0Vu9ueTpKDBCWWdUelrQAkbIGdsocyqiwfgwS6x6XeyZ5iLQYo1X3",
   "audience":"https://contacts-api.com",
   "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}
```

This code works:

```
Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put("client_id", "xoy6LAdnT1wNyo1SijmhZLACrwAgdfyv");
map.put("client_secret","o6FWAhS3crc0Vu9ueTpKDBCWWdUelrQAkbIGdsocyqiwfgwS6x6XeyZ5iLQYo1X3");
map.put("audience","https://contacts-api.com");
map.put("grant_type","client_credentials");
HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
```